# Problem of: io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, rest-assured

I am new in Rest API's. I am trying to run this test function in IntelliJ IDEA to test OMDB API:

```
@Test
    public void shouldNotGetResponseWithoutApiKey(){
        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .queryParam("t", "Harry Potter")
                .get("http://www.omdbapi.com")
                .then()
                .statusCode(401)
                .extract().response();

        assertThat(response.getBody().jsonPath().getString("Error"), Matchers.containsString(errorMessage));
    }
```

Here the logic is: I want this test to give status code 401 since the API Key is not given to the Rest Assured. It's very straight forward. But I receive this error:

```
    io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
    
        at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:627)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268) 
        ...
```

I searched for the error but I couldn't find a solution. I would be very happy if someone can direct me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: shouldn't you use RestAssured.given().queryParam(...).when().get(...).then(...) form? so when() before get()?